# jQuery carousel with the right side slide active and bigger

Tags: html, jquery, css, carousel

I want to create a carousel, like the image below. As you can see the right slide is bigger than the others and it's the active one. I'm open using plugins or pure CSS and jquery, but I want the slide to take the scale swiftly not suddenly. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap framework? If yes then you can achieve without other plugins.

Comment: @Raeesh Alam can you help me with the code

Comment: You can apply a "transform: scale()" to the active slide.

Answer (score 0):

Add `transform:scale()` property  in CSS to active carousel.

> The **[scale()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale)** CSS function defines a transformation that resizes an element on the 2D plane. Because the amount of scaling is defined by a vector, it can resize the horizontal and vertical dimensions at different scales.

Here, 3 carousel active at time so, given `.carousel-item.active .col-md-4:nth-child(3)`

```
.carousel-item.active .col-md-4:nth-child(3){
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

The demo is a bootstrap carousel having card. so, try this.. :)

**[`CODEPEN LIVE DEMO`](https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/NWNEdJW)**